# ubuntu iso downloading another iso file

Tags: installation, downloads

Ubuntu iso file is again downloading the file from the installation and if i proceed with the internet connection closed then in middle of the installation it crashes saying that the files is corrupted

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. The internet connection must stay open throughout the whole download.

There are some programs that enable you to pause the download if you use them but that's not recommended

It is best to download using [torrents](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) to deal with such cases.

Comment: I have done it a many times and wasted around 5 gb for it where it does not solve my problem

Comment: then your best solution is using torrents as Web-E says. If your internet connection stops for any reason then the part you've already downloaded is not lost and the download will continue when you're connected and there's no risk of file corruption.

Comment: welcome, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are you using wget? If yes, use it with the option -c and it you continue your download where it left, if the servers has the capabilities(Most today do).

Comment: i was using wubi installer